# SQL Server edition support

Tags: sql-server-2005, vendor-support

Does anyone know whether Microsoft supports SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition SP2 anymore?

The following is from reported from `@@version`

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (X64) 
Dec 10 2010 10:38:40 
Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (X64) Dec 10 2010 10:38:40 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

As per output you have SQL Server 2005 SP4 and it does fall under category of extended support.

> For main question

SQL Server 2005 SP2 is **not supported at all**. As a fact SQL Server 2005 even with SP4 does not falls under category of normal support however it does falls under category of extended support. As per [MSDN Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlreleaseservices/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2005-and-end-of-service-pack-support-for-sql-server-2008-sp1)

We would like to remind all customers that Mainstream Support for SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3 and SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 4 will end on April 12, 2011, and Service Pack Support for SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1 will end on October 11, 2011.  Microsoft is ending support for these products as part of our Support Lifecycle policy, found in http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle.

Please read MSDN blog for more details

PS: Even if you have Microsoft Premier support and you are at SQL Server 2005 SP2 and raise a case with Microsoft for help they would first ask you to apply SP4 and ask you to see if issue subsides. If not they would take (After applying SP4) your case under extended support

If you want to know difference between mainstream and extended support This [MSDN Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/mainstream-vs-extended-support-and-sql-server-2005-sp4-can-someone-explain-all-of-this) would give you more details